# File Set Not Configured For The File Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

When I open a Spring configuration files at my application on Intellij IDEA sometimes it says

```
File Set Not Configured For The File
```

and gives me a link

```
Configure File Set
```

When I click it it says:

```
MVC dispatcher servlet
Create New File Set
```

or opens a new window cnd let me check some files.

What happens when I click them and what is this for? I click MVC dispatcher Servlet and check the code but doesn't see any changes.

What it is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is for IDEA to help you out with dependencies between different files.

For example you have "service-spring-config.xml" and "mvc-spring-config.xml", where the MVC config uses some beans from the Service config. If you add these both files to the "File Set", IDEA will know that these two files represent a single application context.

By knowing that, it will help you autocomplete beans in XML + will inform you if something is not resolvable without you having to actually *run* the app.

- *I click MVC dispatcher Servlet and check the code but don't see any changes*

This is because you only have a single file (for now). Later on, you can add some other configs that use/reference beans from each other => then it'll become REALLY helpful

From [IDEA File Sets](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/managing-file-sets.html) documentation:

*By combining Spring XML configuration files in a file set you tell IntelliJ IDEA that these files are mutually related. In this way you form a common editing context for these configuration files and get all the associated coding assistance.*

Answer (score 1):

Spring file sets on IntelliJ are for grouping related files.

IntelliJ could autodetect some of this groups, for example files that are loaded with ContextLoaderListener on web.xml or default files for DispatcherServlet (That seems to be your case)

When IntelliJ asks to configure a File Set for a Spring file, is 'cause IntelliJ couldn't detect a default way to include in a group, for example files that are loaded within the ApplicationContext's constructor Ex:

```
new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("somefile.xml","anotherfile.xml");
```

When file sets are correctly configured IntelliJ could bring many goodies like auto-complete, navigation, validation, dependency graphs and others